# React - How to render components inside a function outside of render plus execute same function outside of render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function outside of render. That function returns (conditionally) a component, that function is beeing triggered not inside render, but inside componentWillReceiveProps (which was necessary due to other facts).
My problem is that the function does not end up returning the component and I dont know why. When I call that function inside render, then of it works, but I cant do that as I must call it inside componentWillReceiveProps. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user != this.props.user) {
      this.getData(nextProps.user)
    }
  }

  getData() {
    if (...) {
      return <Child />
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.getData}</div>
    );
  }
}

const Child = () => {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a state called data in the constructor as follows:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={data:""};
}
```

Now, `{this.getdata}` inside `render()` with `{this.state.data}`

Also replace componentWillReceiveProps as follows:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user != this.props.user) {
        var newdata = this.getData(nextProps.user)
        this.setState({data:newdata});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So my getData function only returns true or false. if its true, I render Child component, if false, I render another one. Now I could do in my render function: {this.data==true ? <Child /> : <otherComp />}. Is it correct that there is no other way but to render Child etc inside render based on my state variables value?

Comment: @2018code2018 Hi sorry but I didn't get what you are asking. Can you  tell me what exactly you want to be rendered initially and also when props are received. Also specify if you want anything else done or have a doubt

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't return `children` from other hooks than `render` you will need to keep them in a state:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      someChildren: null
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user != this.props.user) {
      this.setState({ someChildren: this.getData(nextProps.user) });
    }
  }
  getData() {
    if (...) {
      return <Child />;
    }
    return null
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.someChildren}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you component will receive new props, it will re-render automatically, doing like following you should have you component to re-render and being updated:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  getData: () => {
    if (...) {
      return <Child />
    }
    return null;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.getData()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot have that function called inside render, because of other problems, but I guess there is no other way then but dont render components inside my function

Comment: Maybe you should fix the "other problems" then, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only return JSX data in render and not in the other lifecycle function to render. Also render method is pure so for the same input it returns the same output and hence react is able to rightly optimise on performance for the same by maintaining a virtual dom, so you would just write

```
class App extends React.Component {
      getData() {
        if (...) {
            return <Child />
        }
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                {this.getData()}
              </div>
          )
      }
}

const Child = () => {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

and it would have a the same effect, also if you further optimise by using [`React.PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), so that render is called on when there is a prop change. `React.PureComponent` implements `shouldComponentUpdate` with a shallow prop and state comparison.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
         if (nextProps.user != this.props.user) {
         this.getData(nextProps.user)
         }
      }
      getData() {
        if (...) {
            return <Child />
        }
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                {this.getData()}
              </div>
          )
      }
}
```

However to do what you want, you would actually store the date in state of component and then render the data based on state in render method

```
class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state {
             data: this.getData(props)
         }
      }
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
         if (nextProps.user != this.props.user) {
            this.getData(nextProps.user)
         }
      }
      getData(props) {
        if (...) {
            const newData;
            // update newData based on receivedProps here
            // store the data in state
            this.setState({data: newData});
        }
        return [];
      }
      render() {
          return (
              <div>
                {this.state.data.map((obj) => return <Child data={obj}/>)}
              </div>
          )
      }
}
```

Comment: I cannot have that function called inside render, because of other problems. I dont think I could use React.PureComponent as my component has more code and I dont want to affect it. I guess I just cant render components outside of render.

Comment: What kind of problem cause you to not call the function in render, If your getData is pure, you can use it in render, however the other way around is to actually store the data in state and then render JSX in render based on state

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps is React lifecycle method which is invoked as soon as your React Component receive a prop by the parent. Actions that could be performed in there are for example update the state what you are doing instead is calling a getDate method which is returning a React Component  .

A possible implementation could be:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  getData() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return user ? <Child /> : <div />
  }
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
            {this.getData()}
          </div>
      )
  }
}

const Child = () => {
  return <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```